# Crowdin error when I tried to upload translations

Tags: eclipse, configuration-files, crowdin

I've an issue (I'm still blocked), I've created my configuration file like :

> project_identifier: test
>   api_key: KeepTheAPIkeySecret
>   base_url: https://api.crowdin.com
>   base_path: /path/to/your/project
>
> files:
>     -
>       source: /locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
>       translation: /locale/%two_letters_code%/LC_MESSAGES/%original_file_name%

See : https://github.com/crowdin/crowdin-cli

However, I received an error message when I execute my command line to upload translation in Crowdin :

```
error: Seems Crowdin server API URL is not valid. 
Please check the `base_url` parameter in the configuration file.
```

I don't know why it's not working!Thanks for any help !

Comment: I may find the issue : the jar was corrupted. I use another one, and it seems working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crowdin sent me another JAR, 
The last one was not good for windows path.